# Hydra returning all credentials as valid

Tags: brute-force, hydra, http-brute

I am setting up a brute-force with hydra, and receiving valid responses for almost all requests from passwords list. But on the web form I am still getting an error that credentials are wrong. What am I missing in the script?

System set up on the nginx, and the login/password pairs should be correct.

I tried

`sudo hydra -l admin -P 10-million-password-list-top-1000000.txt -u -e snr -s 80 -m '/admin/:nick=^USER^&password=^PASS^' <ip goes here> http-get-form`

But it looks like false-positives
[image]

The question is - what am I doing wrong with the configuration? App has several ports opened, and that is the http one. Is it possible, that authorisation is going through other protocol, not http?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added details. Not sure it is enough, would appreciate any feedback. This is my very first post on such a resource.

Comment: 1) Are you sure it's an http-form-get and not a http-form-post?  2)Is there an error message when the login fails?  My normal parameters for brute-forcing a web login are something like:  "<path_for_login_page>:<parameters_passed_by_post>:<Error_message_received_for_bad_username_or_password>"

Comment: @keniukas Got the same problem with http post form. May the problem be related to mirroring passwords to usernames and vise-versa?

Comment: This has been asked here many, many times. You haven't set success or failure condtions.